# getting rgba background color by jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, rgba

I have an element with `background-color:rgba(1,0,0,0)` and I need to get this value by jquery to do something. I tried `$('.overlay').css("backgroundColor")` but it returns`transparent`. is there any way to get the rgba background-color of an element by jquery ?

by the way, here are my codes :

**html :**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.overlay { background-color:rgba(1,0,0,0) }
```

**jquery :**

```
$('.overlay').css("backgroundColor");
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? If I run the code you provided, I get back `rgba(1, 0, 0, 0)`. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLNNz/2/)

Comment: Im using jquery-1.10.1   !!

Comment: It is a browser issue, in Firefox it returns transparent while in Chrome it returns the actual css property.

Comment: @codingstill then can I use this for an if statement ? I want to say if `background-color` of `.overlay` is for example `rgba(1,0,0,0)`, do something. can I ?

Comment: Why do you need to know if is rgba(1,0,0,0) or rgba(2,0,0,0)?

Answer (score 1):

As @codingstill points out, Firefox returns `transparent`. But you could still do:

```
var bgColor = $('.overlay').css("backgroundColor");    
if(bgColor == 'transparent' || bgColor == 'rgba(1, 0, 0, 0)'){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is just a hack, what if there are similar rules with different color, e.g. .overlay2 { background-color:rgba(2,0,0,0) }. Also, in IE11 it returns nothing at all :(.

Comment: exactly **codingstill**, my if statement is : `if (bgColor == 'rgba(1,0,0,0)) { do function A }'` and `else if (bgColor == 'rgba(2,0,0,0)) { do function B }'` ! firefox will assume both as transparent, so am I going to have problem in firefox ? or the general functionality is the same and my code will work in firefox as well as chrome, etc. ?

Comment: @codingstill: Indeed. You're absolutely right. It returns *nothing* in IE11?! Weird...

Comment: rbga(2,0,0,0) is also defined with a class? If so, you could check if the element has the specific class. @Lasse weird indeed...

Comment: @Pay4m: What *exactly* are you looking for? Transparency?

Comment: I was looking for the color, while I had to have the element transparent and I had to use rgba in my case. I solved my problem and now I'm using background-color and opacity together. thanks :)