# How to extract the alpha transparent value from RGBA background color in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-color

I need to extract the RGBA value's alpha transparent value to check whether the background color is transparent or not. How can I do that using jQuery?

Comment: Is there any code you have tries already ?

Comment: I checked this. But it didn't work for me. The background color is returned as RGB. not as RGBA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599699/getting-rgba-background-color-by-jquery

Comment: I put the code from the other question in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/go5m1tzj/1/), and it behaves as expected, so can you show your code? There may be some mistake in it. Also, which version of which browser on which platform?

Comment: var rgba = $('.page-sidebar-menu').css('backgroundColor');
alert(rgba);

This returns rgb(255,255,255)

Comment: @Sh_88 And what exactly IS the background color? I'm beginning to suspect that it has an opacity of 1.

Comment: The background-color is dynamically set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the color style property, split it by the commas within the RGBA declaration and then parseFloat to get the numerical value of the alpha channel.

I added a check to console a message if there is no alpha channel listed (ie an rgb value only.

```js
var bgCol = $('div').css('backgroundColor');
console.log('Background color is ' + bgCol);

var alpha = parseFloat(bgCol.split(',')[3]);

isNaN(alpha)
  ? console.log('no alpha channel')
  : console.log('alpha channel value is ' + alpha); // gives alpha channel value is 0.1
```

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <p>This is a test </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked!! Thanks a lot :)